# Having problems using SSRS custom authentication and jasig CAS

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, cas, custom-authentication

I'm trying to set up SSRS to use the DotNetCasClient.dll. When I try to merge these 2 instruction sets, one shows how to use CAS authentication while using IIS .NET framework. The other is how to use a custom forms authentication. Has anyone ever got this to work?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281383.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

and

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casc/.net+cas+client

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to create a custom assembly to override the `Authenticate` and `Authorize` methods of the ssrs security. You will need the complete all authorizations because this new class will be used by ssrs and ssrs manager to authorize user's access to report item collections. The `Authenticate` will use your `DotNetCasClient` to grant access, used inside your new custom assembly. Once that is done you will need to configure the ssrs and ssrs manager applications to use your new CustomSecurity module via their web config files.

Comment: This is if you want to overwrite the authentication method that ssrs uses. I guess you could also use forms and pass along an authenticated  cookie or redirect to a page jasig enabled login page.

Comment: On a side note i dont seem to have the path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager   not sure if that indicates I have ssrs installed properly.

Comment: Thanks Ross, I do have that custom DotNetCasClient.dll built and inserted into reportServer/bin ...as well I just installed it into the GAC as that might be where i was running into problems as I was getting Could not load Authentication extension error in my C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles